# Clickable URL in a Winform Message Box?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, url, messagebox, clickable

I want to display a link to help in a message box.  By default the text is displayed as a non-selectable string.

Comment: Sounds like two requests.  Use a Form instead of MessageBox.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One option is display the url in the message box, along with a message and provide the help button that takes you to that url:

```
MessageBox.Show(
    "test message",
    "caption",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
    MessageBoxIcon.Information,
    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
    0, '0 is default otherwise use MessageBoxOptions Enum
    "http://google.com",
    "keyword")
```

Important to note this code cannot be in the load event of the form, the Help button will not open the link.

Comment: Thanks, creative solution that in my case will be sufficient.  Really appreciate it.  (Upvotes to everyone)

Comment: Note that the `"keyword"` will be appended after a # to the URL as an anchor reference. I.e. http://google.com#keyword

Comment: Clicking on the help button with this code in C# doesn't do anything

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`LinkLabel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.aspx) control on your own `Form` for this. Unfortunately, the `MessageBox` form cannot be customized in this way, so you would need to create your own `Form` to mimic the `MessageBox` for your purposes.

Answer (score 5):

MessageBox won't do that. You'll either need to use the TaskDialog (introduced in Vista) or create your own dialog.

--Edit--
There are ways to fake the task dialog on XP.  There are a few articles on CodeProject.com that I've used in the past.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your own form, instead of the built-in MessageBox, and you can use a `LinkLabel` on it.

However on the built-in MessageBox a Help button could be displayed among the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some custom code with `LinkLabel` like this:

```
        if (hyperLinks != null)
        {
            foreach (var link in hyperLinks)
            {
                var linkLabel = new LinkLabel();
                linkLabel.Text = link;
                linkLabel.Width = WhateverParentPanelYouHave.Width;
                linkLabel.Click += LabelClicked;
                WhateverParentPanelYouHave.Controls.Add(linkLabel);
             }
         }
```

Where `hyperLinks` is a list of strings for your links.

Then for your `LabelClicked` handler:

```
      private async void LabelClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        var linkLabel = (LinkLabel) sender;
        var path = linkLabel.Text;
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => Process.Start($@"{path}"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.ShowMessage(ex.Message, @"An Error Has Occurred");
        }

      }
```

Keep in mind, this is your own form with the `LinkLabel` control added to it. You'll have to inherit from `Form` and use the `ShowDialog()` method to display your form with all your controls added to it.