# Is it possible to make formatted MessageBox with http-reference

Tags: .net, winforms, messagebox

I want to show message like "New version of software is available at http://mysite.com" and so "http://mysite.com" part would be clickable. Is it posible using some built in Winforms message dialog ?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833747/clickable-url-in-a-winform-message-box

Answer (score 2):

No.  You can't.

You will need to create your own Dialog box.

An example on CodeProject: [a custom messagebox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/A_Custom_Message_Box.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Apparently there is a way:
[Clickable URL in a Winform Message Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833747/clickable-url-in-a-winform-message-box)

```
MessageBox.Show(     
    "test message",
    "caption",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,     
    MessageBoxIcon.Information,
    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
    MessageBoxOptions.LeftAlign,
    "http://google.com",
    "keyword"
)
```