# Make URL clickable in MessageBox C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, url, messagebox, clickable

How can I make the URL displayed in the MessageBox clickable, such that when a user clicks on it, it will open the link in a web browser?

```
    string msg = "MyApp | v1.0.0.0.1" + Environment.NewLine + 
    "© 2016 MyApp" + Environment.NewLine + "All Rights Reserved." + Environment.NewLine +
    "For more information, visit: http://www.mysitename.com/myapp";
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
```

*This is for an "About" button.*
*Any help would be appreciated.*

I want it to look similar to this screenshot below.

[Screenshot of Speecy's About MessageBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCHhq.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819426/how-to-create-hyperlink-in-messagebox-show

Answer (score 1):

Create your own form and run it with `ShowDialog()`.