# Visual C++ MessageBox display "mail_to" link

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a button for users to click which displays a `MessageBox` containing support contact details for my app. One of those details is an email address, is it possible to embed a clickable link in the `MessageBox` that will open up the users' default email app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MessageBox won't do that, but a custom dialog might. Here's an [MFC solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12147/CHyperLink-a-simple-MFC-HyperLink-button-class-wit).   Here's a [C# 'solution'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833747/clickable-url-in-a-winform-message-box) (more like a workaround), that you might be able to use almost as-is in C++-cli.

Comment: Thanks, got something working now that does the job.