# String Containing Hyperlink

Tags: c#

I have a string which has a hyperlink:

```
string msg = @"Welcome to <a href=\"http://google.com\">Google</a> ";
```

when I use this in a messagebox, the hyperlink does not show as a link.  Is it possible to use a hyperlink in this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833747/clickable-url-in-a-winform-message-box

Comment: Not with a standard MessageBox.Show. You can make your own dialog though.

Comment: Even with a custom dialog, you will still need to parse the string to extract the URL and url text.

Comment: when you write your string literals with `@` at the beginning, you escape your double quotes with `""`  so, `@"Welcome to <a href=""http://google.com"">Google</a> ";`

Comment: You are missing a couple tags on your question. Is this WPF? WinForm? Web?

Answer (score 1):

try removing the ampersand (@)

```
string msg = "Welcome to <a href=\"http://google.com\">Google</a> ";
```

Comment: I think you've missed the boat on this one.  That string was exactly what OP had originally.  What OP is *trying* to do is parse this string to display an actual html link.

Answer (score 0):

I RECOMMEND creating your own dialog easily by creating a new form then dragging a LinkLabel into it, and you can change the LinkLabel properties to redirect you to whatever you want.